# SSLHandshakeException when trying to setup URLConnection

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

I have the following code:

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class TrackWrapper {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
/*
 *  fix for
 *    Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
 *       sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
 *           PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
 *               unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 */
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
   new X509TrustManager() {
      public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
      }

      public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {  }

      public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {  }

   }
};

SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

// Create all-trusting host name verifier
HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
      return true;
    }
};
// Install the all-trusting host verifier
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
/*
 * end of the fix
 */

URL url = new URL("https://somedomain.com:1234");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.connect();

  }
}
```

The first part of that is simply a copypasted quickfix to accept every certificate I've got from another StackOverflow Question (I'm sure that this isn't exactly ready for production), on the second part I try to connect to some SSL-secured site whichs client certificate is in my keystore, I receive the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1806)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:986)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1197)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1181)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
at TrackWrapper.main(TrackWrapper.java:54)
```

As I admittedly am rather clueless about SSL I'd be grateful for some insight and a walkthrough on how to fix this problem.

After some tries I now get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:830)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1555)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:103)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:689)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ClientHandshaker.java:985)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:904)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:238)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:925)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1197)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1181)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
at TrackWrapper.main(TrackWrapper.java:54)
```

Comment: What app server are you running this on and what IDE?

Answer (score 4):

You should have correct SSL certificate in your keystore, of server to whom you are trying to connect. Check these examples. These are working for me.

[example 1](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=867)
[example 2](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=867)

You can export that server certificate from browser (if accessible) or there are other ways to get certificates over the internet. Your certificates should match. Once you get certificate you can make keystore from any tool. alternatively you can make keystore from [this code](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=423).

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked if you need a client certificate?

The error message could also be from the server side.

Also start your client with the parameter `-Djavax.net.debug=all`. There you should see some more hints about what failed.

Comment: How do I add those parameters? I'm rather new to Java Development.

Also, I need a client certificate which I implemented via keytool (or so I thought).

Comment: When calling `java` via the command line you can add the named parameter to the command line.

I dont't know if you need a client certificate and how you can obtain one. This depends on the server you try to connect to.

Comment: Hey there, yes, I've definitely added the client certificate and have just started running my program with the parameter you appended. I do see a lot about SSL Handshakes and apparently now I'm getting a different error, I've updated my question with the new output.

Comment: This now looks like the host is closing the connection. Without the information from the SSL debug output it is now very difficult to help further.